# How to initialize object with EntityCollection?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, dynamics-crm-2011, moq

I need one of my mocks to return a specifically-initialized object. My current setup is:

```
_mockOrganizationService.Setup(
        x => x.Retrieve("serviceappointment", It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<ColumnSet>()))
    .Returns(new ServiceAppointment());
```

However, rather than returning `new ServiceAppointment()`, I need some more like:

```
new ServiceAppointment{new EntityCollection("resources")}...
```

The method under test executes:

```
var sa = serviceAppointment.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("resources");
```

**How do I initialize ServiceAppointment with an EntityCollectionb in order that I do not get a NullReferenceException?**

Answer (score 1):

Given that the service is defined as

```
public interface IOrganizationService {
    Entity Retrieve(string entityName, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet);
}
```

And using [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx) from documentation, An entity could manually be define to use in the test.

```
// Instaniate a serviceappointment object
var serviceAppointment = new Entity("serviceappointment");
// Set the attributes you  want for the test
serviceAppointment["resources"] = new EntityCollection();
// Create mock service
var _mockOrganizationService = new Mock<IOrganizationService>();
//Setup retrieval of entity
_mockOrganizationService
    .Setup(x => x.Retrieve(serviceAppointment.LogicalName, It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<ColumnSet>()))
    .Returns(serviceAppointment);

var service = _mockOrganizationService.Object;
```

This should allow the method under test to be able to call

```
var sa = serviceAppointment.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("resources");
```

provided that `sa` was retrieved using the mocked service.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you want to return a populated object as your `EntityCollection`.

This is a sample application to populate an `EntityCollection` to be used in a `PartyList` field on an `Entity`. The proof is that the console will show 2 when executed.

```
void Main()
{

    var serviceAppointment = new Entity("serviceappointment")
    {
        Attributes = new AttributeCollection() { { "resources", GetResources() } }
    };

    var sa = serviceAppointment.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("resources");

    Console.WriteLine(sa.Entities.Count);
}

public EntityCollection GetResources()
{
    var entityList = new List<Entity>();
    entityList.Add(new Entity("resource")
    {
        Attributes = new AttributeCollection() { { "name", "Truck" }}
    });

    entityList.Add(new Entity("resource")
    {
        Attributes = new AttributeCollection() { { "name", "Tool" } }
    });

    return new EntityCollection(entityList);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mocking [CRM is hard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3P5ZJ6iR64&t=1s).  That why I wrote a framework to make my life easier.  Using [XrmUnitTest](https://github.com/daryllabar/XrmUnitTest) you could write your test like this:

```
var service = LocalCrmDatabaseOrganziationService.CreateOrganziationService<CrmContext>();
service.Create(new ServiceApointment{
    Resources = new EntityCollection();
});

var serviceAppointment = service.GetFirstOrDefault<ServiceAppointment>();
// serviceAppointment will have a Resources Attribute that is empty.
```

Comment: what are the benefits of your framewokr over fakexrmeasy?

Comment: I don't have a dependency on a testing framework, and I provide alot of additional framework around creating and running your test  locally or against a crm server.  Very similar core IOrganizationService Fake concept though.